# Using Swift Need to Check an Array of Ints to see if they will add up to 10

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I need to check the "rank" in an array of playing cards constructed with rank: & suit: (between 1 and 9) and see if any combination of them will add up to 10. The suit isn't relevant, only the rank. Is there a way to calculate that?

for example, if the array.ranks were [8, 7, 6] it would return false

if the array.ranks were [5, 6, 4, 2, 9] it would return true.

The amount of Ints in the array would vary.

Comment: So if a `sublist` of the input list does produces `10` then it should return `true`?

Answer (score 1):

```
extension CollectionType where
  SubSequence : CollectionType,
  Generator.Element : IntegerType,
  SubSequence.Generator.Element == Generator.Element,
  SubSequence.SubSequence == SubSequence {

  func sumsToPos(n: Generator.Element) -> Bool {
    guard n > 0 else { return n == 0 }
    guard let x = first else { return false }
    let t = dropFirst()
    return t.sumsToPos(n - x) || t.sumsToPos(n)
  }

  func sumsTo(n: Generator.Element) -> Bool {
    if n == 0 { return true }
    guard let x = first else { return false }
    let t = dropFirst()
    return t.sumsTo(n - x) || t.sumsTo(n)
  }
}
```

So I ran some performance tests (you can check them out [here](https://github.com/oisdk/SubSum)), and for 10000 arrays on a release build, here's the results:

- At 0.500 seconds, the `has10` function, from @Aderstedt
- At 0.219 seconds, the `check` function, from @appzYourLife
- At 0.012 seconds, the `canAddTo` function, from @Kametrixom
- At 0.006 seconds, the `sumsToPos` method here.

The `sumsToPos` method works only with just positive numbers, whereas the `sumsTo` works with negative as well.

Comment: Your answer is just awesome as always :D

Comment: Since this appears as a more general solution, I wonder if always true for n = 0 , and always false for negative `n` integers is a good choice. For example `[1, 2, 3].sumTo(0)` will always be `true`.

Comment: Hmm. It's interesting. I mean, the question this function should be answering is "does there exist a subset which sums to n". I suppose it depends whether or not you think the sum of an empty set is 0.

Comment: As for negative numbers, I dunno.

Comment: @oisdk as a more general solution, the user might think that `[-1, 1].sumTo(0) == true` and `[2, -1].sumTo(0) == false`

Comment: @oisdk you might test something like `guard let x = first else { return  false}; let t = dropFirst(); return n - x == 0 || t.sumsTo(n - x) || t.sumsTo(n)` or simply a more specific function name. You know ... early generalisation can be evil just like early optimisation ;-)

Comment: Ooh, that's actually quite elegant. Yeah, you're dead right though. I'll do another edit.

Answer (score 0):

First off, note that this can be computationally expensive. The number of subsets with `k` values out of `n` array elements will be `n!/(k!(n-k)!)`.

The first step is to create a function that takes an array and returns an array of arrays, each with one less element:

```
func subsetsWithOneLessMemberThan(array:[Int]) -> [[Int]] {
    var o = [[Int]]()
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        var x = array
        x.removeAtIndex(i)
        o.append(x)
    }
    return o
}
```

Then, call this function recursively until you only have two elements:

```
func has10(array: [Int]) -> Bool {
    var found = false
    if array.count > 2 {
        let subarrays: [[Int]] = subsetsWithOneLessMemberThan(array)
        found = subarrays.reduce(found, combine: { return $0 || has10($1) })
    }

    return found || (array.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + $1 }) == 10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic **backtracking** approach.

The function *simply* search for **every possibile combination** unless it detects that the current combination is **wrong** because the sum of the selected elements is bigger then the target value (in you example 10).

```
func check(sum: Int, cards:[Int], target: Int) -> Bool {
    if sum == target { return true }        
    if cards.isEmpty { return false }
    if sum > target { return false }

    for (index, card) in enumerate(cards) {
        var sublist = cards
        sublist.removeAtIndex(index)
        if check(sum + card, sublist, target) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

You can call it using:

```
func check10(cards: [Int]) -> Bool {
    return check(0, cards, 10)
}
```

Finally you can write:

```
check10([1,2,3,4,5])
```

### Computational complexity

Given `n` cards, you can sort them in `n!` ways. This function, in the worst case scenario, check every possibile way to sort n cards so the **computational complexity** is `O(n!)`.

### Space complexity

This is a **recursive function**. Each time it calls itself, an element is removed from `cards`. When `cards` si **empty** no more recursive calls are performed. So the max number of recursive calls active for a given time is `n`. Then **space complexity** is `O(n)`.

### Optimizations

As said, this approach search for **every possible way** of sorting the cards. However when the function detects that the current `sum` is over the `target value` it does discard the current combination and **skip** to the next one.

We can accelerate this **skipping process** by moving the bigger elements on top of the array by rewriting the second function as follow:

```
func check10(cards: [Int]) -> Bool {
    let biggerFirst = cards.sorted(>)
    return check(0, biggerFirst, 10)
}
```

This does not change the computational complexity (still `O(n!)`), but statistically should help.
The *cost* of this optimization is `O(n log n)` needed to sort the array, very tiny if compared with the huge `O(n!)` of the total approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your code running swift 2 and on the line 'for (index, card) in enumerate(cards)' the Xcode returns 'enumerate' is unavailable: call the enumerate() method on the sequence

Answer (score 0):

I had really fun doing this: A solution using bitwise operators. This solution is most likely faster than the others already posted here (EDIT: Check out @oisdk's answer), because instead of saving and going through all the permutations, I'm using the bit pattern of an `UInt64` as a permutation, therefore I need only a single `UInt64` for a permutation. The only downside is that it won't work when the array has more than 64 elements, but I don't think you need this, also it would take an awful lot of time to check this many permutations (2^64!):

```
func canAddTo(array: [Int], number: Int) -> Bool {
    return (0 ..< 1 << UInt64(array.count)).contains { (perm: UInt64) -> Bool in
        var sum = 0
        for index in array.indices() where perm & 1 << UInt64(index) != 0 {
            sum += array[index]
            if sum >= number { break }
        }
        return sum == number
    }
}

canAddTo([1, 2, 3, 4], number: 10)    // true
```

**Complexity:** `O(2^n)`

**Space:** almost nothing

**Performance:** Didn't test but should be very fast

**Limits:** Theoretical limit of 64 elements

EDIT: Incoporated @oisdk's suggestion and corrected super silly mistake

Comment: Change `array.enumerate()` to `array.indices`, and then change `sum += elem` to `sum += array[index]` and you'll double the speed. (It's weird, I know)

Comment: @oisdk Wow! I guess it makes sense because `elem` doesn't need to be assigned, I'm really only checking for the `index` in the `where` clause, whereas I only need the element when it was true.

Comment: Under the hood, when Swift iterates through an array (or a string, or most things, actually) it iterates through the indices, and indexes back into the array. When you use enumerate it sets up a separate integer iteration

Comment: [This is an alternative enumerate, that uses the indices of the underlying collection](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/blob/master/SwiftSequence/Enumerate.swift)